# How to make a POST request with two arguments (MERN Stack)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I usually try to avoid asking questions this basic, however, I've spent some time trying to figure this out, and cannot come up with anything.
I am new to using MongoDB & Mongoose, as well as Express, so forgive me.

I am making an app that stores user profiles in MongoDB, and am creating an API method in Express that allows users to edit their profile. I am using Mongoose's findByIdAndUpdate(), which takes two arguments, the first being the '_id' of the user, and the second being the object with the new information.

This is how I'm writing the function in Node:

```js
// Edit user profile API
exports.edit = (req, res) => {
  UserProfile.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, {
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      bio: req.body.bio,
    }), {
      new: true
    },
    (err, model) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Success:', model);
      }
    };
};
```

And this is how I'm trying to make the request with POSTMAN, for testing:
[image: POSTMAN request]

The request is stuck on an infinite render.
Mainly, I'm just not sure how to grab the ID in Express.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Sending a request isn't the same as calling a function. Read that endpoint code - it's taking five props from the body of the request (likely expecting JSON, but could be form encoded or something), and using *them* to make two arguments to call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is expecting id parameter to be in the req.body object. So your postman request body should look something like this

```js
{
  "id": "your id",
  "firstName": "firstname",
  "lastName": "lastname",
  "phone": "phone",
  "bio": "bio"
}
```

It's also a good practice to pass the ids as a url parameter.

[In that case your postman would look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUQ6y.png)

And your node.js code would look like this :

```js
exports.edit = (req, res) => {
  UserProfile.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      bio: req.body.bio,
    }), {
      new: true
    },
    (err, model) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Success:', model);
      }
    };
};
```